# Print first element of linked list in C lang

Tags: c, linked-list

While teaching my self how to manage linked lists in C i came across some difficulties. I created a function getNode to create a list of 4 integers. Now i would like to printf the first element of the list, so that i can learn something new. Unfortunatelly, when i try to recall the head node of the list, the program prints the last node. When all code was in main() , there was no problems or what so ever, only when i got to factorize the code the dificulities mentioned have occured. It might be just lacking a pointer, or some sort of logical error. Any help apreciated! thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct list
{
    int x;
    struct list *next;
}list;
list *getNode()
{
    int marker = 0;
    int base;
    list *head, *current;
    head=current=NULL;
    while (marker < 4)
    {
        printf("wprowdz liczbe dla NodE o markerze: %d  \n", marker + 1);
        scanf("%d", &base);
        list *node = malloc(sizeof(list));
        node->x = base;
        node->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            current = head = node;
        }
        else
        {
            current = current->next = node;
        }
        marker++;
    }
    return current;
}
void printNode(list *head)
{
    printf("this shoud print the first element of linked list :");
    printf("%d", head->x);
}
int main()
{
    list *start = getNode();
    printNode(start);


}
```

Comment: `getNode` returns `current` which is the last node. Did you mean to return `head` instead?

Comment: @UnholySheep ok thanks it works so far, although i still need to learn how to manage the list it self, so there will be more precariousnesses to come. thanks !

Comment: @kenshin - I would also suggest searching this site for `"C linked list"`, there are many, many examples that will help. Many are very thorough and complete.

Answer (score 0):

My dear friend, in the function getNode you need to return the head pointer not the current pointer. The head pointer points at the first node but the current node is pointing at the last node because you are updating the current node everytime while loop is executed.
So, we need to return the head pointer in order to traverse through the linked list or print the first element. Hope you get it !! Cheers, feel free to ask questions